# Vertically align multiple labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment

I have a sketch with two aligned lines. These lines have a label each. When you look on my example, you will see, that the labels "Top" and "Inlet" do not share the same baseline. Both labels are placed individually.

How can I define a baseline for both of them?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=20]
% Specify the coordinates
\coordinate (P1) at (-0.125,0.15);
\coordinate (P2) at (-0.0635, 0.15);
\coordinate (P3) at (-0.0605, 0.15);
\coordinate (P4) at (0.0, 0.15);

\coordinate (P5) at (-0.125,0);
\coordinate (P6) at (-0.0635,0);
\coordinate (P7) at (-0.0605,0);
\coordinate (P8) at (0.0,0);

\coordinate (P9) at (-0.102588, -0.03);
\coordinate (P10) at (-0.0605, -0.03);
\coordinate (P11) at (0.0, -0.03);

\draw[line width=0.5pt] (P1) -- (P2) -- (P6) -- (P10) -- (P7) -- (P3) -- (P4);
\draw[line width=0.5pt] (P1) -- (P5) -- (P9);
\draw[line width=0.5pt] (P4) -- (P11);
\draw[line width=0.5pt] (P1) -- (P2)  node [midway, above] {Inlet};
\draw[line width=0.5pt] (P3) -- (P4)  node [midway, above] {Top};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Image generated by the code.]

Comment: `{\strut Inlet}` and `{\strut Top}`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want an "automatic" solution that doesn't depend on the labels, then

```
\draw[line width=0.5pt] (P1) -- (P2)  node [midway, above] {\strut Inlet};
\draw[line width=0.5pt] (P3) -- (P4)  node [midway, above] {\strut Top};
```

can do.

Comment: An even more automatic solution would be to issue `every node/.style={font=\strut}` (globally, to the `tikzpicture` or to another `scope`)

Answer (score 6):

They are not aligned due to the depth of `p` in `Top`. You can use `vphantom{p}` to align them:

```
\draw[line width=0.5pt] (P1) -- (P2)  node [midway, above] {Inlet\vphantom{p}};
```

[image]

Comment: The “opposite” solution would be to add `text depth=0ex` to the `Top` node.

Comment: Does the code "\vphantom{p}" make TikZ align the text "Inlet" in a way, as if the text contained a letter 'p'? And therefore, adjust the spacing between text and line?

Comment: @DohnJoe: It adds a depth of `p` but no width.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel That is a valid (and reasonable) solution, consider posting it as an answer!

Answer (score 4):

*(This answer aims at a alignment that uses the original placement of “Inlet” without adding further (vertical) padding to the nodes.)*

There is a special anchor `.base` that would place the `at` part of the node at the baseline of the text. But this does not help here, as we want to place the node `above` (equivalent to `anchor=south`) of the lines. With `anchor=base` we would get
[image]

Though, `anchor=south` can be mimiced by up-shifting the base-line aligned nodes by the amount of `inner ysep`; key: **`base above`**:
[image]

A very similar solution can be obtained, by setting the `text depth` to zero (and thus ignoring the depth of `p`); key: **`Base above`**:

[image]

The actual difference can be seen by drawing the rectangular shape of the node:
[image][image]

---

If the missing depth of `p` is too tight for you, you can use (as already proposed in the other answers) `\vphantom` or `\strut` (which is just a very big `\vphantom`). But I would rather use a key for this and would not manual insert those macros in the node. We can use the `font` key for that:

- `ssstrut`, `Ag`:

  [image]
- `sstrut`, `()`:

  [image]
- `strut`, `\strut`:

  [image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{
%   nodes={draw,draw opacity=.5},% debug
    base above/.style={%                                     shape does not loose its original measurements
        anchor=base, yshift=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner ysep}},
    Base above/.style={%                                     “smashing” the bottom part
        above, text depth=0ex},
    ssstrut/.style={%                                        very small strut
        font=\vphantom{Ag}},
    sstrut/.style={%                                         small strut
        font=\vphantom{()}},
    strut/.style={%                                          big strut
        font=\strut}}
\newcommand*{\coordinates}{\coordinate (P1) at (-0.125,0.15) coordinate (P2) at (-0.0635,0.15)
                            coordinate (P3) at (-0.0605,0.15) coordinate (P4) at (0.0,0.15);}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=20] \coordinates
\draw (P1) -- (P2) node [midway, base above] {Inlet};
\draw (P3) -- (P4) node [midway, base above] {Top};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=20] \coordinates
\draw (P1) -- (P2) node [midway, Base above] {Inlet};
\draw (P3) -- (P4) node [midway, Base above] {Top};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=20] \coordinates
\draw (P1) -- (P2) node [midway, above, ssstrut] {Inlet};
\draw (P3) -- (P4) node [midway, above, ssstrut] {Top};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=20] \coordinates
\draw (P1) -- (P2) node [midway, above, sstrut] {Inlet};
\draw (P3) -- (P4) node [midway, above, sstrut] {Top};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=20] \coordinates
\draw (P1) -- (P2) node [midway, above, strut] {Inlet};
\draw (P3) -- (P4) node [midway, above, strut] {Top};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```